# WPF - Custom Tab Control Binding

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a custom tab control and the tabs were working fine, but when I click a button in my toolbar, the selected tab disappears.

1. How do I get the selected tab to remain Visible until the next tab is selected?
2. How do I bind the Visibility of the selected tab with the Visibility of it's corresponding toolbar and DataGrid? (Example: If I click on Tab2, I want Tab2Tools and dgTab2 to become Visible, and all other TabTools and DataGrids to be Hidden or Collapsed.

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="TabGradientTop">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TabGradientBottom">#FFC0CBE8</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabBarText" Color="#FF353C66"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabBarTop" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabBarBottom" Color="#FFC0CBE8"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabBarBorder" Color="#FF8E96AC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabMou5eOverColor" Color="#FFFFB700"/>

    <Style x:Key="TabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TabBarText}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="TabNormal" Fill="Transparent"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="TabMou5eOver" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBottom}"  Height="30" Stroke="{StaticResource TabMou5eOverColor}" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="TabMou5eOver2" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBorder}"  Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="TabMou5ePressed" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarTop}" Height="30" Stroke="{StaticResource TabBarBorder}" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TabMou5eOver2" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TabMou5eOver" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TabMou5ePressed" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TabMou5ePressed" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TabMou5ePressed" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="InvisiStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TabBarText}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--Gadients-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Rectangle Height="46">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource TabGradientBottom}" Offset="0.25"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource TabGradientTop}"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBorder}"/>
        <Rectangle Height="87">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource TabGradientBottom}" Offset="0.45" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource TabGradientTop}"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBottom}" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBottom}"/>
        <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBorder}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Tabs-->
    <Grid Margin="15,22,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="cmdTab1" Content="Tab1" Style="{DynamicResource TabStyle}" Width="55" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsDefault="True"/>
            <Button x:Name="cmdTab2" Content="Tab2" Style="{DynamicResource TabStyle}" Width="55" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            <Button x:Name="cmdTab3" Content="Tab3" Style="{DynamicResource TabStyle}" Width="55" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            <Button x:Name="cmdTab4" Content="Tab4" Style="{DynamicResource TabStyle}" Width="55" Height="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <!--Tool Bars-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="Tab1Tools" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,52,0,0" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button x:Name="Tab1Login" Content="Login" Height="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource InvisiStyle}"/>
            <Button x:Name="Tab1Request" Content="Request Password" Height="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource InvisiStyle}"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource TabBarBorder}" Height="1"  Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource TabBarTop}" Height="1"  Margin="5,0,5,5" Opacity="0.5"/>
            <Button x:Name="Tab1Exit" Content="Exit"  Height="18" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource InvisiStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Tab2Tools" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,52,0,0" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="Tab3Tools" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,52,0,0" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="Tab4Tools" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,52,0,0" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <!--Data Grids-->
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgTab2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,137,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgTab3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,137,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgTab4" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,137,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the button click using Command property in your viewmodel and define a method using delegates. In your method you can set the visibility of datagrids as per the requirement.

Regarding your first query, I simply copied your code on my local and tried executing it, I do not see any tabs becoming invisible while the other one is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Arushi.  If you click on the Login button in the toolbar area, you will see the Tab disappear.  The Tabs are set by the IsFocused trigger which looses focus when other templated buttons are pressed.